# Read csv with tab delimiter produces errors

Tags: python, numpy, io, csv

I have a CSV file, which uses a '\t' TAB as a delimiter. It contains 5 columns. I tried this:

```
import numpy as np 
#b=np.loadtxt(r'train_set.csv',dtype=str,delimiter=' ')
my_data = np.genfromtxt('train_set.csv', delimiter='\t')
print my_data
```

but I am getting the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./wordCloud.py", line 7, in <module>
    my_data = np.genfromtxt('train_set.csv', delimiter='\t')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1667, in genfromtxt
    raise ValueError(errmsg)
ValueError: Some errors were detected !
    Line #14 (got 4 columns instead of 5)
    Line #21 (got 4 columns instead of 5)
    Line #135 (got 4 columns instead of 5)
```

Any ideas please? I do not know Python well (yet :))!

---

The dataset (which I also examine right now) looks like this:

[image]

---

EDIT:

If I do:

```
my_data = np.genfromtxt('train_set.csv', delimiter='    ')
```

then I am getting no errors, but the output is:

```
[ nan  nan  nan ...,  nan  nan  nan]
```

---

The answer gives these warnings:

```
...
    Line #26310 (got 4 columns instead of 5)
    Line #26383 (got 4 columns instead of 5)
    Line #26448 (got 4 columns instead of 5)
    Line #26489 (got 4 columns instead of 5)
    Line #26589 (got 4 columns instead of 5)
    Line #26593 (got 4 columns instead of 5)
    Line #26888 (got 4 columns instead of 5)
    Line #27002 (got 4 columns instead of 5)
    Line #27065 (got 4 columns instead of 5)
    Line #27234 (got 3 columns instead of 5)
    Line #27327 (got 4 columns instead of 5)
    Line #27418 (got 4 columns instead of 5)
    Line #27594 (got 4 columns instead of 5)
    Line #27827 (got 4 columns instead of 5)
    Line #27944 (got 4 columns instead of 5)
    Line #28074 (got 4 columns instead of 5)
    Line #28102 (got 4 columns instead of 5)
    Line #28147 (got 4 columns instead of 5)
    Line #28224 (got 4 columns instead of 5)
    Line #28264 (got 4 columns instead of 5)
    Line #28344 (got 4 columns instead of 5)
    Line #28484 (got 4 columns instead of 5)
  warnings.warn(errmsg, ConversionWarning)
```

and the output gets some strange characters, like:

```
costing at least \xc2\xa3429
```

in place of `costing at least £429`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check Line #14, 21, and 135 of your csv file?
These lines do not contain 5 columns, as the error states (all of them contains 4 columns).

If the 5th column is supposed to be blank, simply insert the `\t` character at the end.

Looking at your data, probably this is what you want:

```
my_data = np.genfromtxt('train_set.csv', delimiter='\t',
                        invalid_raise=False, skip_header=1,
                        dtype=None)
```

`invalid_raise`: This will skip the invalid lines (#14, 21 and 135). Please recheck them. (In Libre Office: use 'Save as')

`skip_header`: The name explains itself.

`dtype`: Should be `None`, so that datatype of each column is determined by the contents of that column.

Comment: The lines you are mentioning all have a 5th column. I selected tab as the separator in Libre Office and now it is displayed nicely, so I might say that the dataset is alright. (I updated the screenshot).

Comment: Libre Office is relatively forgiving in this regard. Try opening the file in a text editor. In Libre Office, go to the blank cells of the mentioned lines, enter something in them, then delete the values, and save. Then try the code.

Comment: I also opened with gedit, but a column contains many words, thus I can not see much. Libre Office does not colntain an empty column.

Comment: Sure there is problem with the CSV. In gedit, search for `\t`. There shouldn't be any highlighting at the end of line 14, etc - which means no `\t`.

Comment: But that's true for the former lines too, I can't tell what's happening.

Comment: Count the number of tabs (by highlighting through search) in each line. You should see 4 tabs in each column (because you have 5 columns). If the last column is empty, then there should be a highlight at the end. In the erroneous lines, there would be 3 highlighted tabs. And did the answer solve your problem?

Comment: Line 14 for example has 4 tabs, I checked with gedit! However your answer managed to get some output, see my updated question. Also notice that the output is much smaller than it should be, i.e. it contains only 8 lines, while the dataset has plenty (but you helped enough so far, thanks, I will check).

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. My data are correct (see below) but numpy report such errors:

`Line #11787 (got 4 columns instead of 11)`
`Line #11838 (got 3 columns instead of 11)`

I used python to load data and then convert to numpy. So instead of

`tabOryg = numpy.genfromtxt(fn, dtype='str', delimiter='\t')`

I did:

```
    datas = [i.split('\t')  for i in open(fn) ]
    tabOryg = numpy.array(datas, dtype='str')
```

and it works. I wonder what is wrong with genfromtxt.